# Cassandra 3.0 trigger to update user define type

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra, datastax, cql

I have cassandra table with user define type

```
  CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS signature (
    user TEXT,
    signature TEXT
  );

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
    bank_id TEXT,
    id UUID,
    acc TEXT,
    amount INT,
    signatures SET<frozen <signature>>,

    PRIMARY KEY(bank_id, id)
  );
```

When inserting value for this table I want to track it via cassandra trigger(ITrigger) and update the signature(UDT) of the same row(there's multiple signatures in the row)

I have simply written a class with implementing **ITrigger** and created a CQL trigger statement for it. I was able to take the inserted value from that trigger.

```
public class SignTrigger implements ITrigger {    
    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {
        // take the inserted row

        // TODO update the same row with signature type
    }
}
```

How could I update the same row with user define type via cassandra trigger?

Comment: Why use triggers? Cant your application just make an update? I would strongly recommend avoiding triggers.

Comment: Yes, that could be possible, in that scenario the program needs to periodically listen for inserts of the table(need to have a database table listener). I thought it was kind a overhead. Isn't that an overhead when comparing to trigger?

Comment: Why not just insert the signatures when the transaction is inserted i mean. Theres some gotchas to triggers involving replays and such that are hard to handle and think through. It may even work for your situation here but in general its best to assume triggers are more for internal tooling than regular use.

Comment: In my scenario, different parties(not only the creating party) needs to be sign the transactions, so its not possible to add signature when creating the transaction.